# CodeIgniter: Items Pagination

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pagination

I'm currently having problem with Codeigniter 2.2's Pagination.
What I want is to Display the list of the items if it is included from another table.

To express what I mean, this would be logic.

```
<?php
    $x = 1;
    $this->db->group_by("item_id");
    $query = $this->db->get('item_inventory_inhouse');
    foreach ($query->result() as $row4)
    {
        $this->db->where('item_id', $row4->item_id);
        $query = $this->db->get('items');
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $x++ . '</td>';
            echo '<td><a href="">' . $row->item_id . '</a></td>';
            echo '<td><a href="">' . $row->item_name . '</a></td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row->item_category . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row->item_costprice . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row->item_retailprice . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row->item_tax . '%</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Since I am doing pagination. I can't write the code above.

Well, I tried to formulate some code.
Here is my **Controller**:

```
function pharmacy()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
        $total_row = $this->pharmpagination_model->record_count();
        $config['num_links'] = 2;
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/inventory/pharmacy/';
        $config["total_rows"] = $total_row;
        $config['per_page'] = 30;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<nav><ul class="pagination">';          
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></nav>';          
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li><span aria-hidden="true">';
        $config['next_link'] = '&raquo;';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</span></li>';         
        $config['last_link'] = 'Last';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['first_link'] = 'First';
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li><span aria-hidden="true">';
        $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo;';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</span></li>'; 

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        if($this->uri->segment(3)){
        $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ;
          }
        else{
               $page = 1;
        }
        $data["results"] = $this->pharmpagination_model->fetch_data($config["per_page"], $page);
        $str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data["links"] = explode('&nbsp;',$str_links );

            $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
            $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];   
            $data['title'] = 'Pharmacy Inventory';
            $this->load->view('inventory/pharmacy', $data);
    }
   else
   {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Oops! You have to Login');
     //If no session, redirect to login page
            redirect('login', 'refresh');
   }      
}
```

and here is the **Model**

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class PharmPagination_Model extends CI_Model {
      function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    // Count all record of table "contact_info" in database.
      public function record_count() {
        return $this->db->count_all("item_inventory_inpharmacy");
    }

    // Fetch data according to per_page limit.
    public function fetch_data($limit, $id) {

        $this->db->group_by("item_id"); 
        $mainquery = $this->db->get('item_inventory_inpharmacy'); 
        foreach ($mainquery->result() as $row4)
        {

                $this->db->limit($limit, $id-1);
                $this->db->where('item_id', $row4->item_id);                
                $query = $this->db->get("items");
            }
                if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                        $data[] = $row;
                    }

                    return $data;
                }


        return false;
   }
}
?>
```

It actually worked but it is only showing 1 row, where in fact, it should display 5 rows since there are five rows in the database.

Hope someone can help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you have not provided your data snapshot, it is going to be hard to tell why it's showing one row. i am assuming you have different item_id in the items table and if you look at your model code, that is where the problem is (you are querying item table for each item id but returning the $data array for last item only.)

you can easily do this using join :)

```
public function fetch_data($limit, $id) {
    $this->db->group_by("item_inventory_inpharmacy.item_id"); 
    $this->db->from("item_inventory_inpharmacy");
    $this->db->join("items","items.item_id=item_inventory_inpharmacy.item_id");
    $this->db->limit($limit, $id-1);
    $query = $this->db->get();        
    return $query->result();
}
```